# Exporting data from Postgres to json and renaming the columns of the fly

Tags: json, postgresql

How can I import only certain column from a table in json and rename them on the fly? That is:

```
MyTable (id, column1, column2, columns3)
```

And I want to export to json them as:

```
MyTable: {column11, column2, columns33}
```

So only 3 columns and 2 of them are renamed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Building on [Export Postgres table as JSON](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90482/export-postgres-table-as-json), you can select the data you want from your table, convert it to JSON, and then `copy` it to a file. Here's a [SQLFiddle showing the JSON conversion](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2b308/4).

Let's play with

```
CREATE TABLE data (id integer, name varchar(255), quantity integer);

INSERT INTO data VALUES 
  (1, 'apple', 10),
  (2, 'banana', 20),
  (3, 'cherry', 30)
;
```

First, get the data into the format you want, with fewer columns and any name changes.

```
SELECT
  name AS fruit_name,
  quantity
FROM data;
```

Then, put this in a subquery and convert it to JSON.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fruit_data) FROM (
  SELECT
    name AS fruit_name,
    quantity
  FROM data
) fruit_data;
```

Finally, wrap everything in `copy`.

```
COPY (
  SELECT row_to_json(fruit_data) FROM (
    SELECT
      name AS fruit_name,
      quantity
    FROM data
  ) fruit_data
) TO 'a.file';
```

This will print each row as JSON line by line to the file

```
{"fruit_name":"apple","quantity":10}
{"fruit_name":"banana","quantity":20}
{"fruit_name":"cherry","quantity":30}
```

Postgres can probably build these into an array before you output them, but I think it'd be simpler to postprocess the file into an array if that's the format you want.

Comment: I don't understand this `SELECT row_to_json(fruit_data) FROM (<the data query>) fruit_data;` - what's fruit_data?

Comment: What's `<the data query>`?

Comment: What's `<the JSON query>`? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I was trying to illustrate only the new parts building on previous parts - sorry that was confusing. I've updated the answer to show the full queries at each step.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean "a.json" by 'a.file'?

Comment: Certainly, name it whatever you like. Keep in mind each line is valid JSON, but the file as a whole won't parse unless you wrap it in brackets and add commas to get a real JSON array.

Comment: This is awesome. Now, while I'm able to use a regex to add commas between rows and wrap the entire result set in brackets... I feel there's should be a way to do that in the copy command?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to achieve with [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql):

```
$ psql -U my_user -h my_host -c "SELECT name AS player, score FROM my_table" --csv my_db | spyql "SELECT * FROM csv TO json"
{"player": "David", "score": 5.1}
{"player": "James", "score": 2.1}
{"player": "Joana", "score": null}
{"player": "Hellen", "score": 9.8}
```

We are using psql to export a query to CSV with the desired columns and then spyql to convert the CSV to json lines.

For the record, I created a sample table with the following SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1, 'David', 5.1), (2, 'James', 2.1), (3, 'Joana', NULL), (4, 'Hellen', 9.8)) 
  AS t(id, name, score);
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of spyql